# Is there a negative effect if using @ instead of \

Tags: doxygen

I've been using doxygen for a little while now. The editor(N++) I use creates doxygen comments with backslashes for the special commands.

The doxygen manual says:

> All commands in the documentation start with a backslash ( \ ) or an at-sign ( @ ). If you prefer you can replace all commands starting with a backslash below by their counterparts that start with an at-sign.

So doxygen doesn't really care about it.
Or causes using a \ more trouble than using an @.

Comment: The documentation states that you can do _as you prefer_, so pick up your preferred method and use it. I've used `@` for a while and I've never encountered problems.

Comment: There are other tools besides document that parse javadoc

Comment: I took a look at javadoc. javadoc uses exclusively @-signs for tags/special commands.

Comment: It seems that @{ and @} are not equivalent to \{ and \} though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The backslash is used as an escape character in C/C++, so that `'\"'` is a double quote character for example.

Using `@` for doxygen tags makes it easier to use grep / search the source code.

I always use `@` for this reason.